# How to select the first word of a document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write a quick macro, to save my mail merged documents as separate documents, then save each individual document as the first word in each.

Here is what I have so far, to cut the document up, and save it as "Test_1" and so on, but I'm having trouble adding the code to select the first word.

```
    Sub BreakOnSection()
   'Used to set criteria for moving through the document by section.
   Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowseSection

   'A mailmerge document ends with a section break next page.
   'Subtracting one from the section count stop error message.
   For i = 1 To ((ActiveDocument.Sections.Count) - 1)

      'Select and copy the section text to the clipboard
      ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Section").Range.Copy

      'Create a new document to paste text from clipboard.
      Documents.Add
      'To save your document with the original formatting'
      Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

      'Removes the break that is copied at the end of the section, if any.
      Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
      Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1



      ChangeFileOpenDirectory "H:\Output"
      DocNum = DocNum + 1
      ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="test_" & DocNum & ".doc"
      ActiveDocument.Close
      'Move the selection to the next section in the document
      Application.Browser.Next
   Next i
   ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code:

```
Sub BreakOnSection()
   'Used to set criteria for moving through the document by section.
   Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowseSection

   'A mailmerge document ends with a section break next page.
   'Subtracting one from the section count stop error message.
   For i = 1 To ((ActiveDocument.Sections.Count) - 1)

      'Select and copy the section text to the clipboard
      ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Section").Range.Copy

      'Create a new document to paste text from clipboard.
      Documents.Add
      'To save your document with the original formatting'
      Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

      'Removes the break that is copied at the end of the section, if any.
      Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
      Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

      'Newly Added
      'GoTo Starting of the Document
      Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
      Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=True
      Dim FileName As String
      FileName = ReplaceIllegalChar(Trim(Selection.Text))
      'End

      ChangeFileOpenDirectory "H:\Output"
      DocNum = DocNum + 1
      ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="test_" & FileName & ".doc"
      ActiveDocument.Close
      'Move the selection to the next section in the document
      Application.Browser.Next
   Next i
   ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub

Function ReplaceIllegalChar(strIn As String) As String

Dim j As Integer
Dim varStr As String, xStr As String
varStr = strIn
For j = 1 To Len(varStr)
   Select Case Asc(Mid(varStr, j, 1))
        Case 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122
        xStr = xStr & Mid(varStr, j, 1)
   Case Else
        xStr = xStr & "_"

   End Select
Next
ReplaceIllegalChar = xStr
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 

I get the error - Run-Time error '5096': 
(test_o.doc)    The o being the little black circle 

Debug highlights the following line 

ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="test_" & FileName & ".doc"

D

Comment: Can you share the document on which you get the error. I suppose you are mentioning about the bullet list.

Comment: I can't im afraid, i'm a teacher and it contains a lot of student data. 

It doesn't show a list, it shows  ● in the name .

Comment: Okay. I understand. I have updated the answer and it will now replace any illegal characters like ● to an underscore "_". Check if it is okay with you.

Comment: You absolute beauty. 

Thank you.